# Bounded metrics beyond the bound

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

The [standard bounded metric (see slide 3 of 8)](http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth631/garity/Fall2009/Notes/08_20-2x2.pdf) is defined as $\overline d(x,y)=\min\{1,d(x,y)\}$. For [ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_(mathematics)#Balls_in_general_metric_spaces)s of this metric $B_{r,\overline d}(p) = \{x \in M|\overline d(x,p)<r\}$, they're the same as the balls of the original metric $B_{r,d}(p) = \{x \in M|d(x,p)<r\}$ for $r<1$.

For $r \ge 1$, are all the balls in the standard bounded metric $B_{r,\overline d}(p)$ equal to the whole of $M$?

For another metric $d_q(x,y)=\min\{q,d(x,y)\}$, are the balls in this metric $B_{r,d_q}(p) = \{x \in M|\overline d_q(x,p)<r\}$ also equal to the whole of $M$ for $r\ge q$?

My thinking is that if a point's $x's$ distance $d$ from some central point $p$ is greater than the bound $q$ then $\overline d$ or $d_q$ will force the distance to be $1$ or $q$, respectively, which will be less than $r$, which we choose to be at least $1$ or $q$, respectively.

Comment: Yes , and yes. Both are correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you! Where I can find a book or webpage that says that? It looks obvious, but the fact that my book doesn't say this made me think I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the balls in the standard bounded metric are the same as the balls of the original metric when $r \le 1$, and when $r > 1$ we have $B_{r,\overline d}(p) = M$.

Indeed, consider a discrete metric space $M = \{x,y\}$. Then $d = \overline{d}$ so $B_{1,\overline d}(x) = \{x\} \ne M$.

The situation is exactly the same for the metric $d_q$, we have

$$B_{r,d_q}(p) = \begin{cases}
B_{r,d}(p), &\text{ if } r \le q\\
M, &\text{ if } r > q
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you! Are you still assuming a convention of a strict inequality that is $B_{r,d}(p) = \{x \in M|d(x,p)<r\}$ instead of $B_{r,d}(p) = \{x \in M|d(x,p) \le r\}$? For a strict inequality and $r=1$, it appears we will have for some point $x$ where $d(x,p)>1$, that $\overline d(x,p)=1<1$ and therefore exclude $x$

Comment: Where I can find a book or webpage that says that? It looks obvious, but the fact that my book doesn't say this made me think I was wrong.

Comment: @JackBauer Yes, the open balls have strict inequality. It's not in your book because the situation is completely analogous to when $q = 1$.

Comment: My book does not have a statement for the $q=1$? Do you know of any? I also figured out why $r=1$ is going with the $r<1$. Thank you!

Comment: @JackBauer Well, there is something about it in Munkres' Topology, Theorem $20.1.$ but again nothing special because the claim is quite obvious.

Comment: Yes that's my book. It's also the reference for the slides I linked. Thank you anyway.